# How do I sort dictionary values in a way that respects capitalization?

Tags: python

How can we sort the following dict with respect to the capital alphabet letters i.e `person[:][1][2]`

Thanks

Comment: dicts are not ordered, lists are.

Comment: ok sorry i am new and i try to understand. so ok is list

Comment: @LevLevitsky Not always true. An OrderedDict *is* ordered. See http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict.

Comment: @CodeGnome yep, I was going to post that link, too.

Comment: i tried before but give me a wrong message "NameError: name 'OrderedDict' is not defined"

Comment: @ksofos Right now you have a dict, so to get an ordered structure you need to either create a list of records somehow or use `OrderedDict`.

Comment: `from collections import OrderedDict`

Comment: What do you mean by "sort the following dict"? What should the output be?

Comment: the output will be a same directory and sorted by this letter.

Comment: Don't use a `dict` when you want to re-sort entries. If you want to sort, use a `list`. Even the `OrderedDict` AFAIK is not resortable by arbitrary comparators. **If a `dict` *were* reorderable, it would be *slow*.**

Comment: @Anony: Not slower than a plain list, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably meant to use the values only, not the dictionary. Dictionaries are commonly not ordered, as you want to allow the data structure to be optimized by hashing.

```
sorted(persons.values(), key=lambda item: item[2])
```

is the easiest way to get a sorted list containing the values of your dictionary.

But **maybe you meant to use a `list` instead of a `dict` in the first place?**

Comment: Dictionaries can both be implemented as hash tables *and* have an order. CPython's default implementation is not, however.

Comment: @NiklasB ordered dictionaries are usually btrees, ordered by *key* or *insertion*, not by values. And of course, you can use two structures, a sorted list of keys, and a hashmap, pointing to the same data. You can do that in python trivially, too.

Comment: Just sort the list again, with a different comparator?

Answer (score 3):

This problem is easily solved in modern Python:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> d={....your data....}

>>> d = OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda item: item[1][2]))
```

Comment: OrderedDicts are indeed fatter than regular dicts but your dataset would need to be huge to make a difference in any real application.

Answer (score 1):

```
lst = list(person.items())
lst.sort(key=lambda x: x[1][2])
```

And if you want to sort by letter, then last name, then first name:

```
lst = list(person.items())
lst.sort(key=lambda x: x[1][2] + ' ' + x[1][0] + ' ' + x[1][1])
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'dict_items' object has no attribute 'sort'

Comment: You must have tested this under Python 3.x; I was under 2.x.  I was about to add `list()` to force `person.items()` to expand out to a list, but Lev Levitsky did it for me.